# How to use model generated with pytorch transfer learning module (.pth) in opencv's neural network module (caffe)?

Tags: opencv, pytorch

I have used transfer learning of pytorch to trained a model. It has an extension of .pth. I want to use it to recognize object in video. I have always been using opencv in video processing so I want to use it this time too. However, the dnn module from opencv does not accept model with .pth extension. Can I generate model with pytorch that can be accepted by opencv? Or can I use model with .pth in opencv?

Here's how I saved the trained model

`torch.save(the_model.state_dict(), PATH)`

I have read that post [How should I save the model of PyTorch if I want it loadable by OpenCV dnn module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929573/how-should-i-save-the-model-of-pytorch-if-i-want-it-loadable-by-opencv-dnn-modul?rq=1) but it is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [exporting using onnx](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html), which looks like it could be [read by OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Deep-Learning-in-OpenCV)

Comment: Also, possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929573/how-should-i-save-the-model-of-pytorch-if-i-want-it-loadable-by-opencv-dnn-modul?rq=1

Comment: I have tried this https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html but I dont really understand the way to apply it. Can you give me an example please?